# Numpy Error: this is the wrong setup.py file to run while trying to install Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I tried to install Numpy library with VisualStudio Code (VS Code) used the terminal and official website for [instructions](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/user/building.html)

Even though I followed each step I keep getting "This is the wrong setup.py file to run error"

I tried to update every element to not get an error, deleted and installed NumPy files in the directories which are in site-packages, and my anaconda files (i use jupyter as well but I need to implement this on my VSCode editor).

I also tried to get in the NumPy file and tried

```
pip install.
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I used this site's instructions as well to [install NumPy](https://scipy.org/install.html#pip-install):

here I tried :

```
python -m pip install --user numpy
```

but keep getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to build from source? Can you use `conda install numpy` instead?

Comment: @jakub can you send me instructions step by step please

Comment: @shradha I already tired to upgrade pip, doesn't work

Comment: @shradha this is not the answer

Comment: @Çağatay Şen What is the result when you install the module numpy using "pip install numpy" in the VSCode terminal?  Please try to reload VSCode after installation.

Comment: @JillCheng Yeah I already tried that one multiple times, i just can't get what the problem is. python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory I get same error like this when i reload it

Comment: @ÇağatayŞen  According to the content of this error message, it is recommended that you try to update ‘setuptools’ with "pip install --upgrade setuptools". In addition, what is the environment of VSCode you are currently using? Could you provide us with a screenshot of the console when you installed numpy so that we can check the relevant information?

Comment: @Çağatay Şen Thank you for providing us with the information. In order to protect your information, please cover your personal information such as the username in the screenshot.

Comment: @JillCheng Thank you for warning me, i just deleted that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot you provided, I noticed that the installed module "`numpy`" exists in the "`python3.7`" folder, not in the "`python3.8`" you are currently using.

This is where my environment and `numpy` are located:

[image]

1. It is recommended that you use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal, VSCode will automatically enter the current environment, and then you can use "pip install numpy" to install numpy into "python3.8".
2. Or you can switch the environment directly to the python3.7 environment that includes `numpy`.
3. If it still doesn't work, you can uninstall `numpy` and reinstall it. ("`pip uninstall numpy`", "`pip install numpy`")

Since we are using `pip` to install the module `numpy`, we can use "`pip --version`" to check the currently used pip version, the module is installed in this environment:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, basically your answer is solved my problem! I needed to uninstall my 3.7 environment, and install the latest version. Opening a new terminal couldn't change and update 3.8, i just closed and open the VSCode then it worked. Bless you!